# Why AppLocker automatic rule generation can't read these folders?

Tags: windows-10, security, applocker

Windows 10 Enterprise latest version,
Running AppLocker automatic rule generation on drive C:\ and after it completed its scan, I am getting a message that these folders were skipped.

I need to know:

1. why is this happening?
2. how can make it read them all?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you worried about files contained within a folder that will be automatically deleted in less than 14 days (Windows.old) and a folder that cannot be used by a normal user (WinSxS)?

Comment: Hi, that's true, but what about some files in `C:\program files\WindowsApps` ? only 2 executable of 2 games in there. not sure why they can't be added.

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall the applications contained within WindowsApps you don't want ran?

Comment: Any event the reason an executable launched as a user, even if you elevate those permissions for the executable cannot read WindowsApps is simple, the user themselves do not have access to those folders.